# jQuery Datatables Search & Pagination Issue in server-side processing mode

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I have a problem with jQuery DataTables. I use jQuery DataTables with server-side, the problem is that I can search or paginate table but they don't work together.

For example, I search something and I want to move next page. When I move next page, my search terms disappear.

See [thise page](http://iozkan.com/tests/urunler.asp) for demonstration.

My codes are below:

```
    var Datatable = function () {
    var tableOptions;  // main options
    var dataTable; // datatable object
    var table;    // actual table jquery object
    var tableContainer;    // actual table container object
    var tableWrapper; // actual table wrapper jquery object
    var tableInitialized = false;
    var ajaxParams = []; // set filter mode
    var countSelectedRecords = function() {
        var selected = $('tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) input[type="checkbox"]:checked', table).size();
        var text = tableOptions.dataTable.oLanguage.sGroupActions;
        if (selected > 0) {
            $('.table-group-actions > span', tableWrapper).text(text.replace("_TOTAL_", selected));
        } else {
            $('.table-group-actions > span', tableWrapper).text("");
        }
    }
    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function (options) {

            if (!$().dataTable) {
                return;
            }
            var the = this;
            // default settings
            options = $.extend(true, {
                src: "",  // actual table 
                filterApplyAction: "filter",
                filterCancelAction: "filter_cancel",
                resetGroupActionInputOnSuccess: true,
                dataTable: {
                    "sDom" : "<'row'<'col-md-8 col-sm-12'pli><'col-md-4 col-sm-12'<'table-group-actions pull-right'>>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-8 col-sm-12'pli><'col-md-4 col-sm-12'>r>>", // datatable layout

                    "aLengthMenu": [ // set available records per page
                        [10, 25, 50, 100],
                        [10, 25, 50, 100]
                    ],
                    "iDisplayLength": 10, // default records per page
                    "oLanguage": {  // language settings
                        "sProcessing": '<img src="assets/img/loading-spinner-grey.gif"/><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Bekleyiniz...</span>',
                        "sLengthMenu": "<span class='seperator' style='float:left;'>|</span> _MENU_ <span class='seperator' style='float:right;'>Kayıt listele</span>",
                        "sInfo": "<span class='seperator'>|</span>Toplam _TOTAL_ Kayıt Bulundu",
                        "sInfoEmpty": "Gösterilecek Kayıt Bulunamadı",
                        "sGroupActions": "_TOTAL_ records selected:  ",
                        "sAjaxRequestGeneralError": "İstek tamamlanamadı. Lütfen internet bağlantınızı kontrol ediniz.",
                        "sEmptyTable":  "Tabloda kayıt bulunmuyor.",
                        "sZeroRecords": "Eşleşen kayıt bulunamadı.",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sPrevious": "Geri",
                            "sNext": "İleri",
                            "sPage": "Sayfa",
                            "sPageOf": "of"
                        }
                    },
                    "aoColumnDefs" : [{  // define columns sorting options(by default all columns are sortable extept the first checkbox column)
                        'bSortable' : true,
                        'aTargets' : [ 0 ]
                    }],
                    "bAutoWidth": false,   // disable fixed width and enable fluid table
                    "bSortCellsTop": true, // make sortable only the first row in thead
                    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap_extended", // pagination type(bootstrap, bootstrap_full_number or bootstrap_extended)
                    "bProcessing": true, // enable/disable display message box on record load
                    "bServerSide": true, // enable/disable server side ajax loading
                    "sAjaxSource": "", // define ajax source URL 
                    "sServerMethod": "POST",

                    // handle ajax request
                    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
                      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                        "dataType": 'json',
                        "type": "POST",
                        "url": sSource,
                        "data": aoData,oSettings,
                        "success": function(res, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            if (res.sMessage) {
                                App.alert({type: (res.sStatus == 'OK' ? 'success' : 'danger'), icon: (res.sStatus == 'OK' ? 'check' : 'warning'), message: res.sMessage, container: tableWrapper, place: 'prepend'});
                            } 
                            if (res.sStatus) {
                                if (tableOptions.resetGroupActionInputOnSuccess) {
                                    $('.table-group-action-input', tableWrapper).val("");
                                }
                            }
                            if ($('.group-checkable', table).size() === 1) {
                                $('.group-checkable', table).attr("checked", false);
                                $.uniform.update($('.group-checkable', table));
                            }
                            if (tableOptions.onSuccess) {
                                tableOptions.onSuccess.call(the);
                            }
                            fnCallback(res, textStatus, jqXHR);
                        },
                        "error": function() {
                            if (tableOptions.onError) {
                                tableOptions.onError.call(the);
                            }
                            App.alert({type: 'danger', icon: 'warning', message: tableOptions.dataTable.oLanguage.sAjaxRequestGeneralError, container: tableWrapper, place: 'prepend'});
                            $('.dataTables_processing', tableWrapper).remove();
                        }
                      } );
                    },
                    // pass additional parameter
                    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                        //here can be added an external ajax request parameters.
                        for(var i in ajaxParams) {
                            var param = ajaxParams[i];
                            aoData.push({"name" : param.name, "value": param.value});
                        }
                    },

                    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) { // run some code on table redraw
                        if (tableInitialized === false) { // check if table has been initialized
                            tableInitialized = true; // set table initialized
                            table.show(); // display table
                        }
                        App.initUniform($('input[type="checkbox"]', table));  // reinitialize uniform checkboxes on each table reload
                        countSelectedRecords(); // reset selected records indicator
                    }
                }
            }, options);
            tableOptions = options;         
            // create table's jquery object
            table = $(options.src);
            tableContainer = table.parents(".table-container");
            // apply the special class that used to restyle the default datatable
            $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sWrapper = $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sWrapper + " dataTables_extended_wrapper";
            // initialize a datatable
            dataTable = table.dataTable(options.dataTable);
            tableWrapper = table.parents('.dataTables_wrapper');
            // modify table per page dropdown input by appliying some classes
            $('.dataTables_length select', tableWrapper).addClass("floatleft form-control input-xsmall input-sm");

            // build table group actions panel
            if ($('.table-actions-wrapper', tableContainer).size() === 1) {
                $('.table-group-actions', tableWrapper).html($('.table-actions-wrapper', tableContainer).html()); // place the panel inside the wrapper
                $('.table-actions-wrapper', tableContainer).remove(); // remove the template container
            }
            // handle group checkboxes check/uncheck
            $('.group-checkable', table).change(function () {
                var set = $('tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) input[type="checkbox"]', table);
                var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
                $(set).each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("checked", checked);
                });
                $.uniform.update(set);
                countSelectedRecords();
            });
            // handle row's checkbox click
            table.on('change', 'tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
                countSelectedRecords();
            });
            // handle filter submit button click
            table.on('click', '.filter-submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                the.addAjaxParam("sAction", tableOptions.filterApplyAction);
                // get all typeable inputs
                $('textarea.form-filter, select.form-filter, input.form-filter:not([type="radio"],[type="checkbox"])', table).each(function(){
                    the.addAjaxParam($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val());
                });

                // get all checkable inputs
                $('input.form-filter[type="checkbox"]:checked, input.form-filter[type="radio"]:checked', table).each(function(){
                    the.addAjaxParam($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val());
                });
                dataTable.fnDraw();
                the.clearAjaxParams();
            });
            // handle filter cancel button click
            table.on('click', '.filter-cancel', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('textarea.form-filter, select.form-filter, input.form-filter', table).each(function(){
                    $(this).val("");
                });
                $('input.form-filter[type="checkbox"]', table).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr("checked", false);
                });               
                the.addAjaxParam("sAction", tableOptions.filterCancelAction);
                dataTable.fnDraw();
                the.clearAjaxParams();
            });
        },
        getSelectedRowsCount: function() {
            return $('tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) input[type="checkbox"]:checked', table).size();
        },
        getSelectedRows: function() {
            var rows = [];
            $('tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) input[type="checkbox"]:checked', table).each(function(){
                rows.push({name: $(this).attr("name"), value: $(this).val()});
            });
            return rows;
        },
        addAjaxParam: function(name, value) {
           ajaxParams.push({"name": name, "value": value});
        },
        clearAjaxParams: function(name, value) {
           ajaxParams = [];
        },
        getDataTable: function() {
            return dataTable;
        },
        getTableWrapper: function() {
            return tableWrapper;
        }, 
        gettableContainer: function() {
            return tableContainer;
        }, 
        getTable: function() {
            return table;
        }        
    };
};
```

And

```
 var EcommerceProducts = function () {
    var initPickers = function () {
        //init date pickers
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
            rtl: App.isRTL(),
            autoclose: true
        });
    }
    var handleProducts = function() {
        var grid = new Datatable();

            grid.init({
                src: $("#datatable_products"),
                onSuccess: function(grid) {
                    // execute some code after table records loaded
                },
                onError: function(grid) {
                    // execute some code on network or other general error  
                },
                dataTable: {  // here you can define a typical datatable settings from http://datatables.net/usage/options 
                    "aLengthMenu": [
                        [20, 50, 100, 150],
                        [20, 50, 100, 150] // change per page values here
                    ],
                    "iDisplayLength": 20, // default record count per page
                    "bServerSide": true, // server side processing
                    "processing": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "urun_Listesi.asp", // ajax source
                    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]] // set first column as a default sort by asc
                }
            });
            // handle filter submit button click
            grid.getTableWrapper().on('click', '.table-group-action-submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var action = $(".table-group-action-input", grid.getTableWrapper());
                if (action.val() != "" && grid.getSelectedRowsCount() > 0) {
                    grid.addAjaxParam("sAction", "group_action");
                    grid.addAjaxParam("sGroupActionName", action.val());
                    var records = grid.getSelectedRows();
                    for (var i in records) {
                        grid.addAjaxParam(records[i]["name"], records[i]["value"]);    
                    }
                    grid.getDataTable().fnDraw();
                    grid.clearAjaxParams();
                } else if (action.val() == "") {
                    App.alert({type: 'danger', icon: 'warning', message: 'Please select an action', container: grid.getTableWrapper(), place: 'prepend'});
                } else if (grid.getSelectedRowsCount() === 0) {
                    App.alert({type: 'danger', icon: 'warning', message: 'No record selected', container: grid.getTableWrapper(), place: 'prepend'});
                }
            });
    }
    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {

            handleProducts();
            initPickers();
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: I'd like to help you but there's so much _noise_ in the posted code, I can't follow it! Is it copy/pasted from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

> **CAUSE**

When someone clicks on "Search" button your code does the following:

- adds additional parameters for Ajax request with `addAjaxParam()`
- redraws the table sending Ajax request to the server with `fnDraw()`
- clears all additional parameters with `clearAjaxParams()`

Since parameters are cleared after the request, when pagination occurs the request for data returns all records instead of just filtered ones.

> **SOLUTION**

Try placing `clearAjaxParams()` in the beginning of every function that uses it, so that parameters are preserved for pagination event and cleared only when someone searches again.